# plot/ggplot2 - Fill area with too many points

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

**Final implementation - not finished but heading the right way**

**Idea/Problem:** You have a plot with many overlapping points and want to replace them by a plain area, therefore increasing performance viewing the plot.

**Possible implementation:** Calculate a distance matrix between all points and connect all points below a specified distance.

**Todo/Not finished:** This currently works for manually set distances depending on size of the printed plot. I stopped here because the outcome didnt meet my aesthetic sense.

**Minimal example with intermediate plots**

```
set.seed(074079089)
n.points <- 3000

mat <- matrix(rnorm(n.points*2, 0,0.2), nrow=n.points, ncol=2)
colnames(mat) <- c("x", "y")

d.mat <- dist(mat)
fit.mat <-hclust(d.mat, method = "single")
lims <- c(-1,1)
real.lims <- lims*1.1               ## ggplot invokes them approximately

# An attempt to estimate the point-sizes, works for default pdfs pdf("test.pdf")
cutsize <- sum(abs(real.lims))/100  
groups <- cutree(fit.mat, h=cutsize) # cut tree at height cutsize
# plot(fit.mat) # display dendogram

# draw dendogram with red borders around the 5 clusters
# rect.hclust(fit.mat, h=cutsize, border="red")

library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(mat)
df$groups <- groups
plot00 <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x,y, col=factor(groups))) + 
    geom_point() + guides(col=FALSE) +  xlim(lims) + ylim(lims)+ 
    ggtitle("Each color is a group")
pdf("plot00.pdf")
print(plot00)
dev.off()
```

[image: plot00 - points with group color]

```
# If less than 4 points are connected, show them seperately
t.groups <- table(groups)   # how often which group
drop.group <- as.numeric(names(t.groups[t.groups<4]))   # groups with less than 4 points are taken together
groups[groups %in% drop.group] <- 0                     # in group 0
df$groups <- groups
plot01 <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x,y, col=factor(groups))) + 
    geom_point() + xlim(lims)+ ylim(lims) + 
    scale_color_hue(l=10)
pdf("plot01.pdf")
print(plot01)
dev.off()
```

[image: plot01 - all single points in one group]

```
find_hull <- function(df_0) 
{
    return(df_0[chull(df_0$x, df_0$y), ])
}


library(plyr)
single.points.df <- df[df$groups == 0 , ]
connected.points.df <- df[df$groups != 0 , ]
hulls <- ddply(connected.points.df, "groups", find_hull) #  for all groups find a hull
plot02 <- ggplot() + 
    geom_point(data=single.points.df, aes(x,y, col=factor(groups))) + 
    xlim(lims)+ ylim(lims) + 
    scale_color_hue(l=10)
pdf("plot02.pdf")
print(plot02)
dev.off()
```

[image: plot02 - only "single"-points (less than 4 connected points)]

```
plot03 <- plot02
for(grp in names(table(hulls$groups)))
{
    plot03 <- plot03 + geom_polygon(data=hulls[hulls$groups==grp, ],
                                    aes(x,y), alpha=0.4)
}
# print(plot03)
plot01 <- plot01 + theme(legend.position="none")
plot03 <- plot03 + theme(legend.position="none")
# multiplot(plot01, plot03, cols=2)
pdf("plot03.pdf")
print(plot03)
dev.off()
```

[image: plot03 - final]

**Initial Question**

I have a (maybe odd) question.

In some plots, I have thousands of points in my analysis. To display them, the pc takes quite a bit of time because there are so many points. 
After now, many of these points can overlap, I have a filled area (which is fine!). 
To save time/effort displaying, it would be usefull to just fill this area but plotting each point on its own.

I know there are possibilities in heatmaps and so on, but this is not the idea I have in mind. My idea is something like:

```
#plot00: ggplot with many many points and a filled area of points
plot00 <- plot00 + fill.crowded.areas()

# with plot(), I sadly have an idea how to manage it
```

Any ideas? Or is this nothing anyone would do anytime?

```
# Example code
# install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

n.points <- 10000
mat <- matrix(rexp(n.points*2), nrow=n.points, ncol=2)
colnames(mat) <- c("x", "y")
df <- data.frame(mat)
plot00 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
    theme_bw()  +                       # white background, grey strips
    geom_point(shape=19)# Aussehen der Punkte

print(plot00)
```

[image: ggplot2]

```
# NO ggplot2
plot(df, pch=19)
```

[image: plot]

**Edit:**
To have density-plots like mentioned by fdetsch (how can I mark the name?) there are some questions concerning this topic. But this is not the thing I want exactly. I know my concern is a bit strange, but the densities make a plot more busy sometimes as necessary.

Links to topics with densities:

[Scatterplot with too many points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714677/r-scatterplot-with-too-many-points)
[High Density Scatter Plots](http://blog.trenthauck.com/posts/high-density-scatter-plots/)

Comment: What you ask for is difficult because rendering a solid block depends on the graphical parameters (e.g. point size) that you choose.  To create solid areas you need to buffer the points into a single layer in the same way as a Geographical Information System - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411251/buffer-geospatial-points-in-r-with-gbuffer) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a robust estimator to estimate the location of the majority of your points and plot the convex hull of the points as follows:

```
set.seed(1337)
n.points <- 500
mat <- matrix(rexp(n.points*2), nrow=n.points, ncol=2)
colnames(mat) <- c("x", "y")
df <- data.frame(mat)

require(robustbase)
my_poly <- function(data, a, ...){
  cov_rob = covMcd(data, alpha = a)
  df_rob = data[cov_rob$best,]
  ch = chull(df_rob$x, df_rob$y)
  geom_polygon(data = df_rob[ch,], aes(x,y), ...)
}

require(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=df, aes(x,y)) +
  my_poly(df, a = 0.5, fill=2, alpha=0.5) +
  my_poly(df, a = 0.7, fill=3, alpha=0.5)
```

This leads to:

[image]

by controlling the alpha-value of `covMcd` you can increase/decrease the size of the area. See `?robustbase::covMcd` for details.
Btw.: Mcd stands for Minimum Covariance Determinant. Instead of it you can also use `MASS::cov.mve` to calculate the minimum valume ellipsoid with `MASS::cov.mve(..., quantile.used=`-percent of points within the ellipsoid.

**For 2+ classes:**

```
my_poly2 <- function(data, a){
  cov_rob = covMcd(data, alpha = a)
  df_rob = data[cov_rob$best,]
  ch = chull(df_rob[,1], df_rob[,2])
  df_rob[ch,]
}

ggplot(faithful, aes(waiting, eruptions, color = eruptions > 3)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_polygon(data = my_poly2(faithful[faithful$eruptions > 3,], a=0.5), aes(waiting, eruptions), fill = 2, alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_polygon(data = my_poly2(faithful[faithful$eruptions < 3,], a=0.5), aes(waiting, eruptions), fill = 3, alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

Or if you are ok with un-robust ellipsoids have a look at [`stat_ellipse`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/stat_ellipse.html)

Comment: nice idea, but what if I have 2+ areas?

Comment: that one seems quite good, I will try in the next time, at the moment there's too much stuff todo, but I will probably give a final implementation how I did this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

How about using `panel.smoothScatter` from **lattice**? It displays a certain number of points in low-density regions (see argument 'nrpoints') and everywhere else, point densities are displayed rather than single (and possibly overlapping) points, thus providing more meaningful insights into your data. See also `?panel.smoothScatter` for further information.

```
## load 'lattice'
library(lattice)

## display point densities
xyplot(y ~ x, data = df, panel = function(x, y, ...) {
  panel.smoothScatter(x, y, nbin = 250, ...)
})
```

[image]

Comment: I'm aware of this "density-plotting", it's nice in my opinion, but it's not the thing I have in mind. (sorry :D) - ty nevertheless!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like the [convex hull](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konvexe_H%C3%BClle) of your points:

[image: Convex Hull of points]

```
set.seed(1337)
n.points <- 100
mat <- matrix(rexp(n.points*2), nrow=n.points, ncol=2)
colnames(mat) <- c("x", "y")
df <- data.frame(mat)
ch <- chull(df$x, df$y) # This computes the convex hull

require(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=df, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_polygon(data = df[ch,], aes(x,y), alpha=0.5)
```

Comment: I tried now for about 20 mins. It could! lead to the result i want. First, i want to replace the points below the polygon. Secondly, how would I find connected areas? Maybe a distance-matrix and only the small distances for a polygon?